Audi A4 2010 manual reverse gear issues
I bought Audi A4;in June 2024 . when engine is on it won't go in reverse gear easily .If I turned off and put in reverse it does go into reverse gear .old seller told me that clutch was changed and was not done properly. I took to a mechanic who told me it's need new clutch. I am not sure and confused now what to do .clutch replacement cost lot of money. Can anyone guide me here .I like this car and want to keep it .is it safe to drive for the time being

You might need a replacement clutch, but before you allow that, you should bleed the clutch hydraulic system. A bubble of air in the hydraulic system can prevent the clutch from releasing fully, which would make it difficult to shift to reverse with the engine running. The cost of bleeding the clutch hydraulics is minimal, so it's reasonable to try this before replacing the clutch.
